# Is there a way to install several ClickOnce apps's setups in one go?

Tags: c#, wpf, installation, clickonce

I have made a WPF application that launches other published WPF app setups whenever their corresponding buttons are clicked by using System.Diagnostics.Process.Start() and specifying each of their setup.exe locations (example: D:\Publishedapps\app1\setup.exe).
And it works as Intended because Windows knows to just launch it if its already installed.

But as it is right now the user has to click on every app individually to install/launch to use it, and each app runs its own install process asking for permission to install and all that jazz.

So I want to simplify it for the user by installing the user-selected apps in one go While keeping the launch functionality intact(when the icon is clicked on my app it launches). I think I managed to sort out the user-selected choices using a list.

But I'm stumped on how to install them in one go. I've looked up several other ways to make an installer like WiXSharp and VS's Advanced Installer. But I'm making my own installer as to not be bound by any tools. And maybe because of it, couldn't really find a good solution on the net.
Know any way to run the "setup.exe"s in one go?

Comment: Do you really have to install at all?  Take the stuff out your bin/release folder and filecopy it to a folder of your own in the user's appdatalocal/programs. The user can then run that exe, providing the appropriate .net framework is installed.

Comment: Well, the users of our program have been going to the .htm web page ClickOnce created from our local intranet server and installing from there, And launching from their Start Menu app icon. I was asking if it was possible to do those installation processes in one go. But only the ones the user needs and chosen to install. Without asking for permission on every single one of them and installing individually. Our Clients seems to prefer launching from the Start Menu while some also want to be able launch from our new Package app.